# Override ActiveRecord get properties in Yii

Tags: activerecord, yii, overriding

In my Yii models for some properties I would like to return some default when the real property is null or empty.

For example say I have a `display_name` property. When it hasn't been set, I'd like to return the `first_name`.

So far the work around I've been using is to create a new method with a different name and call this one instead. However it'd be nice if I could achieve this by simply calling `$model->display_name` the normal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have found my own answer. I am overriding `__get()` to check if this is the property I am looking for. I am not sure this is considered "best practice".

```
public function __get($name) {
            $current = parent::__get($name);
            switch($name){
                case 'display_name':
                    if(empty($current)){
                        return $this->first_name;
                    }
                    else{
                        return $current;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return $current;
            }
        }
```

Comment: this will result later in big switch case statements, i've described an easier and cleaner solution in my answer

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already had a similar solution in place. But I was trying to not have to remember alternate functions for all, plus some modules or extensions may not be coded by me.

Comment: I think this will change in version 2. If we define a custom `getX()` method then, even if the model already has an x property defined, then **our** override method should be called instead.

Answer (score 0):

Classes extending `CComponent`, including `CModel`, `CActiveRecord` first will look for a getter method.

In your example, you will have to define a getter function:

```
public function getdisplay_name() {
    if (! empty($this->display_name)) {
        return $this->display_name;
    } else {
        return $this->first_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check CActiveRecord::__get() implmenentation. Your example won't work for instances of CActiveRecord when display_name is a database property.